# Google Sheets web app register several options

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, google-forms

I've taken an example from a book to adapt it. the thing is that the original code has radio check (to enable only one option) and I'd like to have them as checkbocxes (to register several choices). I've made the changes in the HTML code and it looks fine but the spreadsheet still registers one of the choices instead of all of them. 
Could you please let me know what I'm missing?

Here's the HTML of the project

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?= pubUrl ?>">
 <h4>Where will you go for vacation?</h4>
 <? for (var i in places) { ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="places"
 value="<?= places[i] ?>" /><?= places[i] ?><br />
 <? } ?>
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

 </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the GAS (google Script)

```js
function doGet() {
 // Replace with your spreadsheet's ID.
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hpYbBbpVfxsciVCpZGBcqHPeBo2Wuj7U1Y9CaxsI9go");
 var SheetPlaces = ss.getSheetByName("Places");

 var data = SheetPlaces.getDataRange().getValues();

 // Remove header row.
 data.shift();

 var places = [];

 // Populate the places array with the first column's data.
 data.forEach(function(row){
 places.push(row[0]);
 });

 var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form.html");
  
 //Assign the published URL to the template object in the doGet 
template.pubUrl =  "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx90heH12wfP4-kVZCOkEpI7Bi5wqpDAf-ndLrf3bPPYSwwEp5Q/exec";
  //o
  //template.pubUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 // Assign the places array to the template object.
 template.places = places;
 var html = template.evaluate();
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}

function doPost(e){  
  // Replace with your spreadsheet's ID.  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hpYbBbpVfxsciVCpZGBcqHPeBo2Wuj7U1Y9CaxsI9go");
  var SheetResponses = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");   
  // Create a 'Responses' sheet if it does not exist.  
  if(!SheetResponses){     SheetResponses = ss.insertSheet("Responses");
   };    SheetResponses.appendRow([e.parameter.places]);    return ContentService.createTextOutput(     "Your response submitted successfully. Thank you!"  );
}


function createForm() {

 var ThisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var SheetPlaces = ThisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Places");
  
  
 // Load 'Places' sheet data as a 2-dimensional array.
 var data = SheetPlaces.getDataRange().getValues();

 // remove the header row
 data.shift();

 var places = [];

 // Populate the places array with the first column's data
 data.forEach(function(row){
 places.push(row[0]);
 });

 // Create a new form
 var form = FormApp.create("Vacation Form");

 form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
 .setTitle('Where will you go for a vacation?')
 .setChoiceValues(places)
 .showOtherOption(true)

}
```

Also, here's the web app url
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx90heH12wfP4-kVZCOkEpI7Bi5wqpDAf-ndLrf3bPPYSwwEp5Q/exec

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `e.parameters.places`?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry I don't understand your question. "places" is the name of the variable (array) that contains the "destinations" for the "vacations". As I said in my post, I'm taking this code from a book I'm trying to understand (not very succesfuly). "e" is an argument of the dopost function. I don't know where "parameters" comes from.  Thanks for looking into the case, I hope you can help me. Regards!

Comment: In doPost(e) there's `e.parameter.places` Try adding an `s`(as in parameters). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it and it didn't work. In the sheet where responses are collected I'm getting this: "[Ljava.lang.Object;@6565221b"

Comment: `SheetResponses.appendRow(e.parameters.places)`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did that and received the error i clmmented previiusly.

Comment: Note that I also took out  square brackets `[]` in the previous comment. If the error is still the same, You need to learn to debug. `console.log(e.parameters.places)` and view stackdriver logging.

Comment: @themaster you are awesome! It worked perfectly. I can now move on with the priject. Thsnks man